RPM libgcc package conflicts with installed libgcc version newer
I am installing gcc4 (http://v14700.1blu.de/aix/index.php?n=Main.Gcc#v4.8.3) on aix.
One of the dependencies is libgcc 4.8.3-1.I install it via rpm -i libgcc-4.8.3-1.aix7.1.ppc.rpm and get the error: libgcc <= 9.1.0 conflicts with (installed) libgcc10-10.3.0-6.ppcs
How to install 2 versions of libgcc or how else to solve this problem? Deleting libgcc10 is probably not an option, because a lot of other things depend on it

The answer is probably "you can't", since it doesn't appear that the two packages are designed to co-exist. You could extract the libgcc 4.x package manually using rpm2cpio and place the files in a directory of your choice (and then update your build environment to explicitly use that alternate directory).

Please explain why would you want to install an even older version of gcc, when you already have a 10+ year old version installed? (Mind you, gcc version 4.8.3 has a special problem on Aix: it doesn't contain workaround for a known Aix-Assembler-bug, which affects the alignment of bss-sections.)

If you only need libgcc_s.a, you can extract it from the .rpm package with Midnight Commander, or simply use the newer version of it, they are compatible.
